# Spring JdbcTemplate throwing 17004 Invalid column type whtn I insert

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

This code in my Spring Boot app is very simple but its throwing:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO decisions_cache_log ( server_ip, server_hostname, cache_type, load_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Here is the code:

```
            lastCacheLoadCredentials = ZonedDateTime.now();

        sql = "INSERT INTO decisions_cache_log ( server_ip, server_hostname, cache_type, load_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        Object params = new Object[] { "a", "b", "c", lastCacheLoadCredentials.toString() };
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR }; 

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types);
```

All four columns in this Oracle 10 database are VARCHAR2

Thanks...

Comment: Try `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params)` with 2 parameters sql and params without types.

Comment: Actually I did that before I posted, same result :-(

Comment: Following spring documentation this should work `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, "a", "b", "c", lastCacheLoadCredentials.toString());`

Comment: did you try with Types.NVARCHAR ?

Comment: I didn't try Types.NVARCHAR than you, I'll try that. However it seems from what I have read that Types.VARCHAR should be the correct type. But I just need it to work. I did rewrite the code so it builds the SQL directly, so I eliminated the params and types and got it working. But I would still like to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It worked for me only use CallableStatement. It is strange that in other similar procedures there are no problems.